# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1 with userRepository

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

In a spring boot application who are reactive and use jwt, in my spring-cloud-gateway, I have this code.

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SpringSecurityWebFluxConfig {

    private final UserServiceImpl userService;
    private final JwtTokenUtil tokenUtil;

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {
        "/resources/**",
        "/webjars/**",
        "/authorize/**",
        "/favicon.ico"};


    public SpringSecurityWebFluxConfig(JwtTokenUtil tokenUtil, UserServiceImpl userService) {
        this.tokenUtil = tokenUtil;
        this.userService = userService;
    }
    ..
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements ReactiveUserDetailsService, UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserServiceImpl(final UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
    ...

}

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Integer>{
}

public class JWTHeadersExchangeMatcher implements ServerWebExchangeMatcher {
    @Override
    public Mono<MatchResult> matches(final ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    }
}

public class JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager implements ReactiveAuthenticationManager {
    ...

    public JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager(final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, final UserServiceImpl userService) {
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}


public class JwtTokenUtil {
    ...
}

public class TokenAuthenticationConverter implements Function<ServerWebExchange, Mono<Authentication>> {
     private final JwtTokenUtil tokenProvider;

    public TokenAuthenticationConverter(JwtTokenUtil tokenProvider) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }
}

public class TokenAuthenticationConverter implements Function<ServerWebExchange, Mono<Authentication>> {
     private final JwtTokenUtil tokenProvider;

    public TokenAuthenticationConverter(JwtTokenUtil tokenProvider) {
        this.tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }
}
```

> - [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
>     refresh attempt:
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>     Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityWebFluxConfig' defined in
>     file
>     [/home/mac/Development/project/reactive-cloud/gateway-service/build/classes/java/main/com/example/gatewayservice/config/SpringSecurityWebFluxConfig.class]:
>     Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1;
>     nested exception is
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>     Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in file
>     [/home/mac/Development/project/reactive-cloud/gateway-service/build/classes/java/main/com/example/gatewayservice/service/UserServiceImpl.class]:
>     Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>     nested exception is
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>     qualifying bean of type
>     'com.example.gatewayservice.repository.UserRepository' available:
>     expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>     Dependency annotations: {} 2019-06-27 11:47:23.336  INFO 53073 --- [
>     main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Tried to put autowired

on UserServiceImpl in SpringSecurityWebFluxConfig class
on UserRepository in UserServiceImpl class
on UserServiceImpl in JWTReactiveAuthenticationManager.class

but get same error

Edit

if i use

@EnableR2dbcRepositories to GatewayServiceApplication, I dont't have this error but it search about DatabaseClient

Answer (score 0):

Please add @Autowired annotation in UserServiceImpl class for UserRepository variable in constitute constructor or variable level.

Comment: "If a bean has one constructor, you can omit the @Autowired", from [Spring Beans and Dependency Injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html).